# File Systems in Bootloader

Tags: operating-system, bootloader

I was going through boot loader tutorials and found that all the boot loaders use BPB and FAT(this can be any thing) file system.

I am confused about necessity of file system in boat loaders. Is it really required? Why can't we just read enough disk sectors in memory so that we don't need FAT or any file system for that matter?

What happens if we follow below steps:

1. BIOS loads stage 1 boot loader at 0x7C00.
2. Using BIOS interrupt, stage 1 boot loader reads stage2 boo loader in memory. Now this can be tricky. We need to load enough sectors in memory so that stage 2 is completely in memory.
3. Jump 2 stage2 boot loader. Address where we loaded stage2 in previous step.
4. Stage2 does initialization and processor mode switching. Jump to kernel(kernel can be loaded along with stage 2 itself, or stage 2 can read kernel into memory).
5. Jump to kernel main. Start executing

Comment: You can. It's just easier to handle files than raw disk when writing the required code to disk

Comment: For loading a kernel that has no support files then no real need for a file system. Just place the kernel anywhere on disk and read it fromit. As your OS grows and you need to start storing multiple files to be loaded into memory when need a file system can be very useful. If you use a known  file system(EXT2/FAT etc) then it also easier to copy files to your OS media without having to write files to a fixed location on the disk. If you are starting out, you don't need a file system right away, but eventually you'll find yourself wanting one as the OS grows

Comment: @Michael Petch I realized that kernel part will need os for sure later on. I am confused about bootloader reading files using FAT table. Can we not just load kernel after stage2 and later on kernel will take care of loading files using FAT as required.

Comment: If you place the 2nd stage somewhere that doesn't conflict with the FAT file system then you can avoid the bootloader reading the file system directly. For media without a partition table (containing a BIOS parameter block) you can fit basic FAT code to read the second stage entirely within the bootloader from the file system itself. Many people don't bother, but it is an interesting exercise. In early versions of DOS the  bootloaders looked for required DOS files to continue the boot process in certain parts of the FAT directory to reduce code needed in the boot sector to find files it needed

Comment: @MichaelPetch I need a help regarding your previous answer on how to create disk image from binary boot loader code.  In mac-os I am not able to create iso file with FAT12/16/32 partition which can be loaded in virtual box.   I want to get .iso file from the steps. 1) Create image file(OS.iso) with FAT12 file system. 2) Copy stage2 boot loader using dd command. 3) copy stage2.bin as normal file in OS.iso. 4) Give this file as input to virtual box so that I will be able to test my boot loader and kernel later. Any help ?